# CKEditor change target depending on link protocol

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using the current version of CKEditor and I have set `targetField['default'] = '_blank';`
However, if anyone inserts a `javascript:` link (which are sometime needed in my application), I would like the target to change to `<none>`.

Any idea how to do that?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a front-end sanitization tool such as [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) to do sanitization